# Change the this.size function to individual width and length?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to change the width and height of a function so I can properly display an image.

```
function Bullet(x, y, size, vy, type) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.size = size;
  this.vy = vy;
  this.type = type;
}
    
Bullet.prototype.draw = function () {
  ctx.drawImage(laser, this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
};
    
Bullet.prototype.update = function () {
  this.y -= this.vy;
};
```

At the moment, the image is there but it is very condensed and looks like a white block

Comment: You can play with the arguments passed into `drawImage()`. You can see what each argument does by looking at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage). This would mean changing the size when you initialize your object

Comment: Looks like the size is determined by the caller of this function. Please share that code too.